# Wordpress custom pagination is redirecting to index.php, how can I solve this?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, pagination, uri

I have a custom theme in WordPress and I just created a custom pagination for a custom query.

Once I click page 2 or higher, it will redirect me to `[URL]/[URI]/page/2`, yet in my screen it will only show the code in `index.php`.

Somehow this URI with this new parameter (`page`) is loading the wrong file in my WordPress theme. How can I solve this?

This is my query:

```php
  //Parametro para saber cuantos posts abran por pagina! 
            $post_per_page = 6;

            //Extracción de la pagina actual
            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;


            // set up or arguments for our custom query
            $query_args = array(
              'post_type' => 'recetas_practicerdo',
              'category_name' => 'dia_a_dia',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
              'paged' => $paged
            );

            // create a new instance of WP_Query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Pagination is working good and it echoes the right content. Every button in my `<ul><li>` elements are correct.

Yet the result is the wrong file. =(

Answer (score 0):

After sesarching for a while I decided to use the get_template_part( ) function in wordpress.

I grab my URI and created some logical rules. If they were true, load the template from where my pagination should be redirecting.

I know it's not the best solution but didn't find any answer on the web.

Some answers said that pagination with custom wp_queries should break some plugins (which is my case).

Also, after I load the right template, I had to also create a head-title for every redirect I did.

If someone knows how to really fix this problem, I will be grateful with the help.

Answer (score 0):

Got to admin settings and change Blog pages show at most to 1. This helped me but I don't know what is the issue.